# adding a chart control to a placeholder ASP.net VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to add a manually created chart to a placeholder but when i look at the output all i get is a blank.. I am getting the data from a dataset datatable that is the last table in the dataset. I only has two colums "Industry" and "industryTheta" any help is much appreciated. I'm not sure whats wrong here

```
 Dim chrt As New Chart
            chrt.ID = "dynChart"
            chrt.Height = Unit.Pixel(1000)
            chrt.Width = Unit.Pixel(1000)
            chrt.BackImageWrapMode = ChartImageWrapMode.Scaled
            chrt.BorderlineColor = Color.Black
            chrt.ImageLocation = "~/TempImages/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)"
            chrt.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.None

            Dim ca As New ChartArea
            ca.Name = "IndustryTheta"
            ca.AlignmentOrientation = AreaAlignmentOrientations.All
            ca.AlignmentStyle = AreaAlignmentStyles.All
            ca.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = True
            ca.Area3DStyle.LightStyle = LightStyle.Realistic
            ca.Area3DStyle.Inclination = 30
            ca.BackHatchStyle = ChartHatchStyle.None

            chrt.ChartAreas.Add(ca)

            Dim sers As New Series
            sers.Name = "IndustryName"
            sers.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie
            sers.Label = "#VALX, #PERCENT"
            sers.LabelAngle = 90
            sers.IsXValueIndexed = True
            sers.IsValueShownAsLabel = True
            sers.XAxisType = AxisType.Primary
            sers.YAxisType = AxisType.Primary
            sers.YValuesPerPoint = 1
            sers.XValueMember = "Industry"
            sers.YValueMembers = "IndustryTheta"

            chrt.Series.Add(sers)

            For Each dr As DataRow In table.Rows
                Dim p As New DataPoint
                p.SetValueY(Convert.ToInt32(dr.Item("IndustryTheta")))
                p.AxisLabel = dr.Item("Industry")
                sers.Points.Add(p)
            Next

            chrt.DataBind()

            dynamicGrids.Controls.Add(chrt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your problem is with when you are calling your function in the page life cycle.  Please refer to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) information to learn more about it.

In order to address dynamic controls in asp.net please refer to [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/shahed/archive/2008/06/26/123391.aspx) for more information on dynamic controls.